# How to add Favicon Icon in Next Js 13 App Router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

How can I change the favicon icon for Nextjs 13 using app router for routing ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add like this:

```
export const metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: '/icon.png',
  },
};
```

Comment: export const metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: '/icon.png',
  },
};

This Worked for Me, Just add it in your Layout.tsx file

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I've added that to other properties in the exported metadata at `/app/layout.tsx` and no luck. Could you please provide a link to the documentation where it's mentioned?

Comment: Also you might need to remove the default favicon.ico file from the app directory. Thanks to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48392#issuecomment-1512868952 for this idea.

Comment: where is this documented?

Comment: what if it is on client side rendering?